# Register custom Gamepad class with GamepadEvent results in Failed to convert value to 'Gamepad'

Tags: javascript, typescript, gamepad

I'm trying trying build a little virtual controller as Gamepad class and register it.

For now it is a copy of the Gamepad class:

```js
class MyJoystick {
    readonly axes: ReadonlyArray<number>;
    readonly buttons: ReadonlyArray<GamepadButton>;
    readonly connected: boolean;
    readonly hapticActuators: ReadonlyArray<GamepadHapticActuator>;
    readonly id: string;
    readonly index: number;
    readonly mapping: GamepadMappingType;
    readonly timestamp: DOMHighResTimeStamp;

    constructor() {
        this.axes = [];
        this.buttons = [];
        this.connected = true;
        this.hapticActuators = [];
        this.id = "my-id";
        this.index = 200;
        this.mapping = "standard";
        this.timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    }
}
```

Using

```js
const event = new GamepadEvent("gamepadconnected", {
    gamepad: new MyJoystick() as Gamepad
})
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Failed to construct 'GamepadEvent': Failed to read the 'gamepad' property from 'GamepadEventInit': Failed to convert value to 'Gamepad'.
TypeError: Failed to construct 'GamepadEvent': Failed to read the 'gamepad' property from 'GamepadEventInit': Failed to convert value to 'Gamepad'.
```

**Question:** How can I create my own Gamepad class implementation which I can also register with an `GamepadEvent`?

Comment: If you can, just having `class MyJoystick extends Gamepad` should work

Comment: @vrugtehagel adding extends and super() causes js to throws illegal constructor errors.

Comment: Since it's an interface - adding `implements Gamepad` will still result in the same error message.

Comment: I see - on closer inspection, it seems the spec defines some internal slots for `Gamepad` instances, which you cannot create as an author. Unless there is a specific API to create one (there currently isn't) I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Also, I know these types of comments are not helpful in answering the question, but what's the reason you're trying to implement a "virtual" gamepad in the first place? The gamepad APIs seem to be for listening to _real_ connected devices. Similarly, I wouldn't expect to be able to create a "virtual pointer device".

Answer (score 0):

The browser is expecting a real game controller, not just any object that looks like one.

Now, if you're trying to pretend there's a game controller for testing, here are some ideas:

1. Pretend. Instead of trying to tell the browser there's a real game controller, you can just pretend in your own code. This way, your code thinks there's a game controller, but the browser doesn't get involved.

   ```
    const myFakeGamepad = new MyJoystick();

    // Tell your code to use the fake game controller
    navigator.getGamepads = function(){
      return [myFakeGamepad];
    };
   ```
2. Use a library: There are tools out there that help you pretend there's user input, like a game controller. I recommend the `puppeteer`. It uses a web browser and can pretend to do things like press buttons.
3. Hardcore: Change the browser's code. This one **is** a bit wild, but you could technically change the browser's code to accept your fake game controller. But honestly, that's a lot of work and might be overdoing it.

I'd say the first option is probably your best bet